# How to update few columns in an itemtype with an ImpEx based on a condition?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex, hybris-data-hub

Hybris:I want to update few attributes in an itemtype based on a condition.
Example: If isCreated attribute is false in some records, I want to set it true.

Can anyone please help me with this? How to achieve this scenario with impex?

Comment: This link may help : https://answers.sap.com/questions/12767995/flexible-search-in-impex-import.html

Comment: Is there a alternate way of finding the solution for this question. As the above (URL) solution needs dburl, dbpassword. Can anyone please provide me the alternative solution for this question?